# Why isn't non-unique id warning visible in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

On some page I get this chrome warning:

```
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #Name: (More info: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms) 
<input disabled=​"disabled" id=​"Name" name=​"Name" />​ 
<input id=​"Name" name=​"Name" type=​"hidden" />​
```

I'm using Chrome: Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I tried to repeat the problem by displaying next code in Chrome, but there is no Warning?

Shouldn't two same ID's be enought for this warning to show? What have I missed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <input id="Name" name="Name" />
   <input id="Name" name="Name" /> 
   <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Even if you wrap input elements with **form** the Warning is still not shown

Answer (score 1):

This warning would be shown for form fields. 
So If you'll wrap it with `<form></form>` - you'll see this warning.

Comment: Tried it, does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the barest minimum HTML I was able to trigger the warning with:

```
<input id="foo">
<input id="foo">
```

Apparently, the warning is only triggered if at least one `input` is outside of any forms. If all the dupe inputs are wrapped in forms, they are somehow not detected. The following does not trigger the warning:

```
<form>
    <input id="foo">
    <input id="foo">
</form>
<form>
    <input id="foo">
    <input id="foo">
</form>
```

But the following does:

```
<form>
    <input id="foo">
    <input id="foo">
</form>
<input>
```

This makes zero sense, so I believe it to be a bug in Chrome engine and subject to change in the future.

*Chrome: Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

*Final note:* The warning does not seem to be triggered at all for local files. Try loading your HTML from a valid URL, over your web server of choice.